Setting up connection string in .NET Aspire
Starting with the Aspire starter solution I've added the ability to reach out to an Azure SQL Server database. In my AspireSample.ApiService I have the following line in Program.cs
builder.AddSqlServerClient("SqlClient");

Also in my AspireSample.ApiService I have the following lines in appsettings.Development.json
  "Aspire": {
    "Microsoft": {
      "Data": {
        "SqlClient": {
          "ConnectionString": "Server=tcp:myserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;Authentication=\"Active Directory Default\";",
          "DisableHealthChecks": false,
          "DisableMetrics": true
        }
      }
    }
  },

While this works, I don't understand why I have to place that configuration in my AspireSample.ApiService instead of my AspireSample.AppHost project. Am I missing something around configuration that would allow my ApiService to read the value from my AppHost project?

It's not the host that connects to the database. The aspire host orchestrates its services, it doesn't offer a shared configuration service and certainly doesn't copy JSON files between the services. A configuration service would be another component. If you think about how the Configuration middleware works, sharing configuration isn't done by copying JSON files but connecting to a common configuration provider. That could be a JSON file in a specific place, eg a folder. More likely though, it would be a separate service

In a Kubernetes environment the settings are provided by Kubernetes itself as environment variables, not JSON files. JSON copying or even having the host act as a central configuration service would create a lot more problems than it solved

I understand that the host isn't connecting to the database, but I'm thinking of the database as a resource within the solution. If I had created the database via the AppHost then I would get the connection to that database from a reference configured through the AppHost. I don't follow why I couldn't have a friendly name for a connection string that is controlled by the host.

There is a way, through external parameters. When developing locally, the values are provided from the host's appsettings.json.

You could use only a connection string. Then Aspire doesn't set up a local container or an Azure SQL Server for you. Configure "ConnectionStrings" in 'AppHost/appsettings.json' for "name". In your 'AppHost/Program.cs' put var db = builder.AddConnectionString("name");. Then add .WithReference(db) to any project in AppHost that needs a SqlClient.  The added project's builder.AddSqlServerClient("name") is the same in any case.

If you were to add
var sql = builder.AddSqlServer("SqlClient");

to the AppHost program.cs file, then when starting the AppHost, it will set up a local SQL container and provide the connectionstring (as env variable) to your ApiService, enabling you to work locally without needing the Azure SQL instance.
Using "SqlClient" as the name is not the intention, you would rather name it according to the service that is serves: "Billing", "WebShop", "Todo", "Blogging", ...
Imho it also makes more sense to add the actual database:
var sql = builder.AddSqlServer("Billing")
                 .AddDatabase("BillingProjections");

Aspire will then provide you a ConnectionString in the environment variables:
ConnectionStrings__BillingProjections: 
Server=127.0.0.1,64579;User ID=sa;Password=xxx;TrustServerCertificate=true;Database=BillingProjections

Which for other environments (ex: local testing with localdb, see below) you can also easily replace with a value in appsettings.json (or other environment vars, keyvault, ...)
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "BillingProjections": "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=BillingEngineDb;Integrated Security=True;Application Intent=ReadOnly;"
  }
}

This avoids needing the Aspire specific appsettings configuration.

That assumes someone wants to manage the SQL database as part of their application. If the database is external to the application, then using the app settings is completely valid and can be accomplished through external parameters as mentioned in the question's comments.

I don't know if this is still a problem, but I came across this problem as well and figured it might help someone else out. I tried the external parameters and that didn't work out for me while trying to connect to my local database and not the container. Here is what I did to get around this.
First put the connection string in the appsettings in the Apphost.
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "sql": "your_connection_string"
    }
}

Then in the AppHost.Program.cs
string connectionString = builder.AddConnectionString("sql").Resource;
var database = builder.AddSql("sqlResource")
                      .WithConnectionStringRedirection(connectionString)
                      .AddDatabase("sqlDb");

This passed along the connection string to your application.
